# static keyword error in complex number's class

Tags: c++, static, complex-numbers

i have following  code

```
#include<math.h>
class complex
{

public:
    double getRe();
    double gerIm();
    void setRe(double value);
    void setIm(double value);
    explicit complex(double=0.0,double=0.0);
    static complex fromPolar(double radius,double angle);
    complex operator+(complex rhs);
    complex operator-(complex rhhs);
    complex operator*(complex rhs);
    complex operator+(double rhs);
    complex operator-(double rhs);
    complex operator*(double rhs);
    complex conjugate();
    double norm();
    complex operator/(double rhs);
    complex operator/(complex rhs);

private:
    double real;
    double img;

};
complex operator+(double lhs,complex rhs);
complex operator-(double lhs,complex rhs);
complex operator*(double lhs,complex rhs);
complex operator/(double lhs,complex rhs);
complex exp(complex c);
inline double complex::getRe(){return real;}
inline double complex::gerIm(){ return img;}
inline void complex::setRe(double value) {  real=value;}
inline void complex::setIm(double value) { img=value;}
 inline complex::complex(double re,double im) :real(re),img(im){}
 inline static  complex complex::fromPolar(double radius,double angle){

     return complex(radius*cos(angle),radius*sin(angle));

 }
 inline complex complex::operator+(complex rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real+rhs.real,this->img+rhs.img);

 }
 inline complex complex::operator-(complex rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real-rhs.real,this->img-rhs.img);

 }
 inline complex complex::operator*(complex rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real*rhs.real-this->img*rhs.img,this->real*rhs.img+this->img*rhs.real);

 }
 inline complex complex::operator+(double rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real+rhs,this->img);

 }

 inline complex complex::operator-(double rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real-rhs,this->img);

 }
 inline complex complex::operator*(double rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real*rhs,this->img*rhs);

 }
 inline complex complex::operator/(double rhs)
 {
     return complex(this->real/rhs,this->img/rhs);

 }
 inline complex complex::operator/(complex rhs)
 {

     return (*this)*rhs.conjugate()/rhs.norm();


 }

 inline double complex::norm()
 {
 return (this->real*this->real+this->img*this->img);
 }

 inline complex complex::conjugate()
 {

     return complex(this->real,-this->img);
 }


 inline complex operator+(double lhs,complex rhs)
 {
     return rhs+lhs;
 }

 inline complex operator-(double lhs,complex rhs)
 {
     return complex(lhs-rhs.getRe(),rhs.gerIm());

 }
 inline complex operator*(double lhs,complex rhs)
 {
     rhs*lhs;

 }

 inline complex operator/(double lhs,complex rhs)
 {
     return rhs.conjugate()*lhs/rhs.norm();

 }
```

but is says that

```
1>c:\users\daviti\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\complex_number\complex_number\complex.h(38): error C2724: 'complex::fromPolar' : 'static' should not be used on member functions defined at file scope
```

if i remove static keyword,it compiles fine,but i have used this static keyword in class definition,so if i remove it,would not be error?

Comment: Please use `std::complex<double>` from header `<complex>`. Your division for instance may over/undeflow in some cases.

Comment: in which case?for example when divisor is 0?

Comment: When both operands are eg. around 10^200 (or 10^-200), the result is well defined but your method overflows. See eg. http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/astrophysik/HEA/internal/Numerical_Recipes/f5-4.pdf . Similar remarks apply when you compute the modulus (use `|x| * sqrt(1 + (y/x)^2)` if `|x| > |y|`, `|y| * sqrt(1 + (x/y)^2)` else instead of plain `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`). As a general rule, don't write complex number classes yourself when there is a perfectly good one in the standard library (works also for matrices).

Comment: thanks a lot,but can i use it for FFT?fast fourier transform?

Comment: same for FFT, use a library and don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `static` only needs to appear in the class definition, and not where you implement the method.

```
class complex
{
    //......
    static complex fromPolar(double radius,double angle);
    //.....
};

inline complex complex::fromPolar(double radius,double angle){
     return complex(radius*cos(angle),radius*sin(angle));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Luchian has answered the question sufficiently well. I will discuss an alternative  for `fromPolar`.

Probably you already know that you cannot write this:

```
class complex
{
    //..
    explicit complex(double real, double imaginary);
    explicit complex(double radius, double angle); //same as above
};
```

The second constructor is basically same as the first one (different names for parameters don't make any difference), so you cannot do this, which is why you came up with `fromPolar` solution.

But a subtle problem is still there even in `fromPolar` solution : what is the unit of *angle* parameter? Is it radian, degree or what?

So I would propose the following class which solves both problems discussed above and you wouldn't need `fromPolar` function anymore.

```
class complex
{
    //..
    explicit complex(double real, double imaginary);
    explicit complex(double radius, Angle angle); //now it is different
};
```

where `Angle` is another class defined as:

```
class Angle 
{
  double m_value; //always maintain this in radian

 public:
  Angle(double value, bool isradian = true);

  double radian(){ return m_value; }
  double degree(){ return m_value * 180 / PI; }//or maybe M_PI is the symbol
};
```

Hope that makes your class a little better.

Comment: bu i need constructor for  Angle yes for each  time,i call m_value as a parameter right?

Comment: @dato: No, `m_value` is made `private`, so you cannot use that. You've to use `angle.radian()`, or if you need angle in degree (for whatever reason), you can call `angle.degree()`.

Comment: but i have to declare constructor like Angle(double value):m_value(value){}  right yes?

Comment: I don't really follow you here: afaict radians being much more common, I guess the easier is just to have one *free function* `polar` which returns a complex number from modulus and argument in radians, and let the user add the proper `M_PI / 180` factor at the calling site (oh, wait, this is what `std::complex` does). If you do want to go with the angle solution (I'd use `boost::units` for this, but still), at least provide an enum, not a flag, so that the meaning of the extra parameter is clear at the calling site.

Comment: @dato: Yes. While initializing `m_value`, you also need to check the value of `isradian`.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Enum is a good idea, but I wanted to make it short and omitted *more* robust options. I wanted to convey the basic idea.

Comment: ok  thanks a lot of,one additioncal  question ,how can i use it for,for example fourier transform?

Comment: @dato: I've no idea what you're asking.

Comment: i have complex number's class yes,can i use it for FFT?P\ fast fourier transform i meant

Comment: @dato: To answer that, I've to do a little bit research on the net which I cannot do now, as I'm busy with something else. Why don't you do that yourself, and if you come across any problem, post another topic.

Comment: ok no problem ,thanks for help,i will research it now and in case of any problem,will post here